# Where are the Desktop Applications Listed?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 on PC. Where is the menu located which will give me GUI access to all the installed Software, Programs and settings?
I can only see the Help Menu.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) dash? click on the ubuntu logo in the top left corner and type the name of the application you want

Answer (score 2):

Consider read the [Ubuntu Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/index.html), and the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) to know how to use Ubuntu with Unity desktop environment.